# PHP Configuration To Support Arabic

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have created a mysql database conected to an android app through php, this is my configuration file:

```
<?php
$username="aaaaa";
$password="bbbbb!";
$host="localhost";
$database="dbname";
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb4");
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password, $database) or die(mysqli_error($con));
?>
```

What is the addition or modification to support the Arabic language, as the Arabic writing appears as question marks.
Note: The encoding of the database, tables and fields is utf8_general_ci.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: How can I add this line to my code : $dbh = new PDO('mysql:charset=utf8mb4');

Comment: You are using `mysqli` not `PDO`. Please complete reading the answer in the link it covers `mysqli` too.

Comment: Since you're using mysqli, you can't use a PDO-specific line of code. Look again at the answer for the mysqli version of that setting.

Comment: I added these two lines and the problem is still there: $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb4");

Comment: in database server I found: server charset: cp1252 West European (latin1). is it the problem?

Comment: Yes, cahnge `cp1252` to `utf8mb4` in your database server too.

Comment: Can I change it or is that the responsibility of the hosting company manager?

Answer (score 0):

utf8mb4 handles all the Arabic characters.

Something is set up incorrectly for you to get "?".  See [*utf8 trouble shooter*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) and search for "question mark".